# Doing Correct Calculations with Binary Star Systems

Tags: orbit, binary-star

I've been experimenting with Binary Star System calculations but came across some issues.

I can correctly calculate the Semi-Major Axis of the Earth's orbit around the Sun by doing the equation:

[image: T=2pi*SQRT(a^3/GM)]

Using data from Wikipedia.

```
a = (1.521e11 + 1.47095e11) / 2.   <- average radius of Earth's orbit (meters)
μ = G * M = 6.67408e(-11) * 1.98847e30 gravitational constant * Mass of Sun (kg)
```

I got ≈ 31557884 seconds which equates to ≈ a year

Now my issue is that I've been searching around for a formula that calculates the period and etc of a Binary System where two masses (such as stars) orbit around each other.

So then I try essentially the same formula, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_period):

[image: T = 2pi * sqrt(a^3 / (G(M1 + M2)))]

I used data from the [Procyon A and B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procyon) (binary system)

```
a = Semi-Major Axis = 4.3 AU
M1 = Procyon A Mass = 1.499 Solar Masses
M2 = Procyon B Mass = 0.602 Solar Masses
```

these give me a T (period) of 4731227. It says 40.82 years on Wiki.

What am I doing wrong? Is it the data? is it the formula? My comprehension of the question? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Welcome to Astronomy! For starters, in case you are in a hurry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_mass but I think someone will write a full answer fairly soon.

Comment: or [Two-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem), *also or* [Gravitational two-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_two-body_problem).

Comment: T[s], a [m], M [kg]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The semi-major axis is 4.3 *arcseconds*. At a distance of 3.51 parsecs, this corresponds to 15.09 au. Using your formula I get 40.3 years, which is close enough given the 2 significant figure precision of the semi-major axis.